# Find the number of solutions of $a_0+a_1+a_2=17$ if $2\le a_0\le 5$, $3\le a_1\le 6$, $4\le a_2\le 7$.

Tags: number-theory, generating-functions

> Find the number of solutions of $a_0+a_1+a_2=17$ if $2\le a_0\le 5$,
>   $3\le a_1\le 6$, $4\le a_2\le 7$.

This is an exmaple given by my professor, and his solution is:

> The number of solutions to this equation satisfying the given
>   constraints is equal to the coefficient of $x^{21}$ in the expression
>   $$\left(\sum_{n=2}^5x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=3}^6x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=4}^7x^n\right)=x^9\left(\sum_{n=0}^3x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^3x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^3x^n\right).$$
>   This must be 3, since the coefficient of $x^8$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^3$ is
>   3.

I understand actually nothing here. The expression of summation just pops up, and then comes the answer. What I only know that the idea of generating function is used here.
Can someone help explain how the steps in the solution come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[generating function.](http://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/~animeshm/generating_funct.pdf)

This is another method that you may be interested.

$2\le a_0\le 5$, $3\le a_1\le 6$, $4\le a_2\le 7$.

$0\le a_0-2\le 5-2$, $0\le a_1-3\le 6-3$, $0\le a_2-4\le 7-4$.

$0\le b_0\le 3$, $0\le b_1\le 3$, $0\le b_2\le 3$.

$ a_0-2 = b_0, a_1-3 = b_1, a_2-4 = b_1$

$ a_0 =b_0+2,  a_1 = b_1+3, a_2 = b_2+4$

$b_0+b_1+b_2+2+3+4 = 17$

$b_0+b_1+b_2 = 17-9 = 8$

Now $y_0 = 3-b_0, y_1 = 3-b_1, y_2= b_2 = 3-b_2, y_i's \gt 0$

$9-y_0+y_1+y_2 = 8$

$ y_0+y_1+y_2 = 1$

The number of solutions  $= {(1+3-1)\choose(3-1)} = {3\choose2} = 3$

What I have given you is another solution using stars and bars.

$(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)(x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)$ is what your professor has shortened with summation signs.

How did you get this, the first expresssion in the bracket corresponds to values that $a_0$ can take. The way it is represented in generating function is $a_0=0$ is 1, $a_0=1$ is $x$, $a_0=2$ is $x^2$ and so on.  $a_0$ can take values of {2,3,4,5} hence the first four terms of $x$ in the first bracket.  Next a_1=3 is $x^3$, $a_1=4$ is $x^4$. $a_1=5$, is $x^5$ and $a_1=6$ is $x^6$.  and hence the first four terms of x in the second bracket and now you can figure out how the thrid bracket of x terms are derived.

Now take $x^2$, $x^3$ and $x^4$ from all three bracketed expresssions what you then have is

$$x^2(1+x+x^2+x^3)\cdot x^3(1+x+x^2+x^3)\cdot x^4(1+x+x^2+x^3)=x^9(1+x+x^2+x^3)^3$$

What you are looking for is the coefficient of $x^{17}$, since we already took out $x^9$, we are looking for the coefficient of $x^8$ which is second term of the expansion of the expression in the brackets.  if you expand $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^3$ using the binomial theorem, the equation becomes

$$(1+x+x^2+x^3)^3=\sum_{n=0}^3\binom{n}{3}1^n(x+x^2+x^3)^{3-n}$$

There can't be $x^8$ in $(x+x^2+x^3)^0$, $(x+x^2+x^3)$, and $(x+x^2+x^3)^2$, so $x^8$ appears only in $(x+x^2+x^3)^3$. Note that

$$(x+x^2+x^3)^3=(x+x^2+x^3)^2\cdot (x+x^2+x^3)=(x^6+2x^5+\dots)(x+x^2+x^3)$$

Hence, we obtain that the coefficient of $x^8$ is 3.

Comment: I feel so sorry that I haven't learned stars and bars, but I kind of understand what you're doing here. Can you explain the problem using generating function?

Comment: I have given the explanation.

Comment: I edited your answer to make things more clear, and my last question is why the coefficient of $x^{17}$ is the number of solutions to the equation in the title. That is, why we can use this generating function to obtain the answer?

Comment: There are a different number of ways how $a_0, a_1. a_2$ could play out to a sum of 17.  The GF includes all these  values as factors in its series, when you multiply, it gives a polynomial in which $a_0, a_1. a_2$ takes different combinations within the scope of their range.  But we want is the sum of those combinations that will yield the total to be 17.  $x^17$ could happen in many different ways of $a_0, a_1. a_2$ assuming values in their range.  The coefficient is the collective number of these combinations.

Comment: I have included an article for you to read on gf. in the answer where there are applications of gf in counting problems.

Comment: Sorry, I can only have access to that link once, and I found just now that the file I had downloaded was broken. Can you send the link again?